# Pulling a single variable off a webview in android?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I need to pull a value from a hidden div tag when using a webview. I have turned on javascript in my webview activity but its not liking the "".  HOW can I achieve my goal?

```
public class buttonOne extends Activity{

 WebView wb = null;

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.buttons);
  wb = new WebView(this);
  wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  wb.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
  wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  wb.loadUrl("http://ishopstark.com/mobileapp.php?category=1");
  setContentView(wb);

 }

 private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
   view.loadUrl(url);
   <script type="text/javascript">
     {
        var varSendText = document.getElementById("sendtextcoupon").value;  
     }
     </script>

   return true;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Do you have to escape it? \"text/javascript\"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a short example of how to [inject Javascript into a WebView](http://lexandera.com/2009/01/injecting-javascript-into-a-webview/).

If you actually want to get the value and use it in your Java code, you're going to have to register a JavascriptInterface like in this example - [extracting HTML from a WebView](http://lexandera.com/2009/01/extracting-html-from-a-webview/)

Comment: ok I think I'm close. But how do I get the variable out of the function?            wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
       @Override  
       public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)  
       {  
           String varSendText = null;
     wb.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +   
                   " var varSendText = document.getElementById('sendtextcoupon').value; " +  
                   "})()" + "return" + "varSendText");  
           Toast.makeText(button2.this, varSendText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
       }  
   });

Comment: @Sabanim - You'll have to register a JavascriptInterface callback like in the second example: write a class/method, call addJavascriptInterface() on the webView, passing in the class you created and a variable to call it in the Javascript, then in the webviewClient.onPageFinished() method, use the variable you created in addJavascriptInterface() above, call the method you created, and pass the variable in you want to access.

Comment: Ok. I think I'm getting closer to understanding. I have the example working.           This is where I am choosing what to read from the web page [browser.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.showHTML('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");]         But I can seem to modify it to just give me that value of a hidden tag on that page. I can only get it to give me the full page in an alert box.  should not "document.getElementById('id of tag').value" work?

Comment: @Sabanum - Yes, showing the full page source in an alert box is what the example does... if you replace the 'document.getElemen‌​tsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML' in the example with 'document.getElementById('id of tag').value' it should show the value in the alert box instead. Unless it can't get any value - then the alert box won't show up (because the message is empty).